Fixed surface for a limit cycle
Suppose we have an autonomous dynamical system $\dot{x} = f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is $C^1$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose we have a forward invariant convex and compact set $S$ and a limit cycle $\gamma \subset S$.
Does there exist a set $H \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ which is an immersion of the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (i.e., the set $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$), such that the boundary of $H$ is $\gamma$, and $H$ is forward invariant? If this is false in general, what conditions could be imposed to make it true?
Any answers or relevant reference recommendations would be highly appreciated.
